# background-attachment: fixed don't work in ios- four Parallax in elementor for iPhone and iPad

Tags: css, parallax, elementor

My problem was at the beginning background-attachment: fixed for IOS, well i found this solution with the css code, then a second problem had developed, maybe you have a second solution for me.
I have four parallaxes on the site and I have this code for CSS 
Because I have four parallaxes and I can't change the image or I can't say that in css that I want that first, then the next one and so on, because of the z-index!
If you could answer me I would be very grateful.
What can I do?

```css
.element1{
    background-attachment: scroll;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 64.063em) {

.element1 {
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
}

.parallaxsection1::before{
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
        background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH5zB.jpg");

    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh; 
    width: 100vw;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -11;
}
.parallaxsection1::before{
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
        background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ4V5.jpg");

    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh; 
    width: 100vw;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -11;
}
```

```html
<section class="parallaxsection1" >
<div class="element1" >

</div>
   </section>
   <section class="parallaxsection2" >
<div class="element1" >

</div>
   </section>
   <section class="parallaxsection3" >
<div class="element1" >

</div>
   </section>
   <section class="parallaxsection4" >
<div class="element1" >

</div>
   </section>
```

Comment: Please could you make your snippet so that it shows the problem. I guess you know that background-attachment: fixed has problems in iOS - is that the problem you are asking about

Comment: @AHaworth Yes, you are right, that was my problem at the beginning as well, well I found this solution with the css code, then a second problem developed, but I will write that about it, thank you